# Is the inverse of a diagonal dominant matrix also diagonal dominant?

Tags: linear-algebra, inverse

Is it guaranteed that the inverse of a diagonal dominant matrix, whose elements are all nonnegative, is also diagonal dominant?

In my specific problem, I have a diagonal dominant complex matrix $\mathbf{A}$. Then, I calculate the following:

$$ \left(\left| \mathbf{A} \right|^2\right)^{-1}$$
where the operator $\left| \cdot \right|^2$ is the element-wise absolute value squared, which guarantees the elements of the matrix to be inverted ($\left| \mathbf{A} \right|^2$) to be nonnegative.

My objective is to state confidently that $\left(\left| \mathbf{A} \right|^2\right)^{-1}$ is also diagonal dominant, with the assumption that the values in the main diagonal of 
$\left| \mathbf{A} \right|^2$ are at least 10 to 100 times bigger than the off diagonal values. This assumption holds for my specific application, which is irrelevant for the discussion.

On MATLAB, it seems reasonable. Would someone present a counter example?

Comment: Try $A=\pmatrix{3&2\\0&1}$.

Answer (score 3):

$$A=\begin{pmatrix}2&1&1\\0&1&0\\0&0&1\end{pmatrix}\;,\;\;A^{-1}=\begin{pmatrix}\frac12&\!\!-\frac12&\!\!-\frac12\\0&\;\;1&\;\;0\\0&\;\;0&\;\;1\end{pmatrix}$$

So $\,A\;$ is diag. dominant with all its entries non-negative, but its inverse is not even diag. dominant since in the first row

$$\left|\frac12\right|=\frac12\rlap{\,\;/}\ge \left|-\frac12\right|+\left|-\frac12\right|=1$$

Comment: @igorauad , what do you mean by $\,|A|^2\;$ ? As you talk of the main diagonal I gather this is not the squared determinant of $\,A\,$ , so...?

Comment: Ok, then $$|A|^2=\begin{pmatrix}4&1&1\\0&1&0\\0&0&1\end{pmatrix}$$and I can't see the estimation you mention in your first comment above...

Comment: A more realistic example would be: $\left| \mathbf{A} \right|^2 = \left( \begin{array}{ccc} 100 &0.8 &1.2\\ 0.9 & 95 & 1.05 \\ 0.5 & 1.5 & 120\end{array} \right)$

Comment: @igorauad: If you're interested in specific aspects, you need to better define them in your question. You mentioned nothing about the relative magnitudes of the elements of $A$.

Comment: @igorauad, ""realistic"" for whom, for what or from what point of view?

Comment: I agree, but, initially, I did not have an insight about the most general case, such that I didn't think the specific was necessary (sometimes too specific question sound not interesting for the community). Anyways, I edited the original.

Answer (score 0):

If $A$ has the form $c(I-S)$, where $c \in\mathbf R$ and the one or infty norm of $S$ is $< 1/2$, then you can show via Neumann expansion that $(I-S)^{-1}$ is diagonally dominant, and the scaling factor c is obviously irrelevant for that property. When norm $S$ is $\leqslant 1/2$ you still have weak diagonal dominance. Above that you get counterexamples instantly.